# Map a set of values in python

Tags: python

What would be the best approach to do the following:

```
if lang=="en-US":
    chapter="chapter"
if lang=="fr-FR":
    chapter="chapitre"
# etc.
```

Essentially I'm looking for a mapping that would do something like:

```
lang = ['en-US', 'fr-FR', ...] --> chapter = ['chapter', 'chapitre', ...]
```

How would I accomplish this? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I always use a dictionary for that.

```
langs = {
  "en-US" : "chapter",
  "fr-FR" : "chapitre"
}

test = langs['en-US']
```

But for translations, you should also consider [gettext](http://docs.python.org/library/gettext.html#gnu-gettext-api).

Answer (score 3):

[Dictionaries](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#mapping-types-dict) are good for this.

```
>>> chapter = {
...     "en-US": "chapter",
...     "fr-FR": "chapitre",
...     # ...
... }
>>> chapter['en-US']
'chapter'
>>> chapter['fr-FR']
'chapitre'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> chapter = {
...     "en-US": "chapter",
...     "fr-FR": "chapitre",
...     # ...
... }
>>> chapter.keys(), chapter.values()
... (['en-US', 'fr-FR'], ['chapter', 'chapitre'])
```

If you are looking for translation then best option is [gettext](http://docs.python.org/library/gettext.html).